# Do there exist at least one composite $c$ for which this procedure never ends?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, prime-factorization

Suppose that we take some composite number $n$ and factor it as $n=\prod_{k=1}^{m(n)} p_k^{a_k}$ where $p_1 < ... < p_{m(n)}$ and then we observe what happens when we concatenate the $p_1,...,p_{m(n)}$.

For example $70=2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7=257$ and $257$ is prime and the procedure can be stopped.

But, $121=11 \cdot 11=1111$ and $1111$ is not prime so we continue to obtain $1111=11 \cdot 101=11101=17 \cdot 653=17653=127 \cdot139=127139$ and $127139$ is a prime so the procedure can be stopped.

Surely, the question of whether there exists at least one composite number $c$ for which this procedure never stops can be asked, and I am interested if there really is at least one such $c$.

Are there some results with which we can prove that there is (or that there is no) such $c$?

Comment: I've just tried this with Mathematica: already for $n=49$ it is not clear whether the procedure stops or not.

Comment: @Aretino How many steps you obtained with $n=49$?

Comment: I don't know: I stopped the computation after 5 minutes and 48 steps, with the last result having 86 digits.

Comment: @Aretino :D That´s great!

Answer (score 2):

The procedure that you describe is known as [Home prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_prime).
As far as I know, the status for the starting value 49 is currently unknown (as it involves factoring huge numbers).